# How to update the specific user's data in two tables from sql using php

Tags: php, mysql, session, sql-update

I want that each of the user will update their inputted data only, but I don't know how to do that? Please help me

Here is my code:

```
<?php
include ("../db_connection.php");

$seller_id = $_SESSION['seller_id'];
$trade_name = $_POST ['trade_name'];
$s_address = $_POST ['s_address'];
$opening_time = $_POST ['opening_time'];
$opening_days = $_POST ['opening_days'];
$order_cutoff = $_POST ['order_cutoff'];
$seller_delivery_time = $_POST ['seller_delivery_time'];
$area_covered_delivery = $_POST ['area_covered_delivery'];
$delivery_fee = $_POST ['delivery_fee'];

$sql = mysqli_query($db, "UPDATE selling_details
                    SET
                    trade_name = '$trade_name'
                    s_address = '$s_address'
                    opening_time = '$opening_time'
                    opening_days = '$opening_days'
                    order_cutoff = '$order_cutoff'
                    seller_delivery_time = '$seller_delivery_time'
                    area_covered_delivery = '$area_covered_delivery'
                    delivery_fee = '$delivery_fee'
                    WHERE seller_id= '" . $_SESSION['seller_id'] . "' ");
if ($sql){
    header('location: Seller/seller_menu.php');
}else{
    echo "error insert";
}
?>
```

Comment: So whats the problem in above query? you had not mentioned your error? please specify your current output

Comment: My problem is that it says: Undefined variable: _SESSION in C:\xampp\htdocs\ordering_system_LATEST\Seller\db_selling_details.php on line 5

Comment: Are you storing your session value of  seller_id ?

Comment: Yes sir, I am  storing the session value to seller_id

Comment: this is my condition right, then the query that is executed is an "error insert" if ($sql)
    {

        header('location: Seller/seller_menu.php');
    }
    else
    {
        echo "error insert";
    }
    ?>

Comment: @lucy_charm as I suggested in my answer before first check your variable inside session is defined or not? did you checked that using isset() function

Comment: Yes sir I did and I got the output "error insert"

Comment: please post your that code where you had checked that variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add `session_start();` at the beginning of your php file , in `db_selling_det‌​ails.php`

**EDIT 1**

to have better error reporting change the code `echo "error insert";` to `echo "error occured : " . mysqli_error($db);`

**EDIT 2**

The query should have commas between each ***field = 'value'*** like

```
UPDATE selling_details
                    SET
                    trade_name = '$trade_name',
                    s_address = '$s_address',
                    opening_time = '$opening_time',
                    opening_days = '$opening_days',
                    order_cutoff = '$order_cutoff',
                    seller_delivery_time = '$seller_delivery_time',
                    area_covered_delivery = '$area_covered_delivery',
                    delivery_fee = '$delivery_fee'
                    WHERE seller_id= '" . $_SESSION['seller_id'] . "' ");
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151241/discussion-on-answer-by-ahmed-wessam-how-to-update-the-specific-users-data-in-t).

Answer (score 0):

Before running that query first check your session is present or not

You can check variable is defined or not using isset($_SESSION['seller_id'])